# running ngrok http 80 gets a black screen and I am not able to get the external url to connect to

Tags: ngrok

I started to use ngrok to create a tunnel to get http 80 access to some local files.

It was working great till tonight.

When I run ngrok http 80  I get the usual startup screen for about 30 seconds then a black screen comes up and i am unable to get my external link.

This will load then the terminal window goes blank

```
ngrok                                                                                                                                                                                                                   (Ctrl+C to quit)

Session Status                connecting
Version                       3.1.0
Latency                       -
Web Interface                 http://127.0.0.1:4040

Connections                   ttl     opn     rt1     rt5     p50     p90
                              0       0       0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00
```

```
# ngrok http 80 --log stdout
INFO[11-05|09:28:17] no configuration paths supplied
INFO[11-05|09:28:17] using configuration at default config path path=/root/.config/ngrok/ngrok.yml
INFO[11-05|09:28:17] open config file                         path=/root/.config/ngrok/ngrok.yml err=nil
t=2022-11-05T09:28:17-0400 lvl=info msg="starting web service" obj=web addr=127.0.0.1:4040
t=2022-11-05T09:28:22-0400 lvl=warn msg="failed to check for update" obj=updater err="Post \"https://update.equinox.io/check\": context deadline exceeded"
panic: send on closed channel

goroutine 48 [running]:
go.ngrok.com/lib/tlsx.CRLVerifyConfig.verifyIssuer.func1()
        go.ngrok.com/lib/tlsx/crl.go:104 +0xf5
go.ngrok.com/lib/nsync.(*Group).Go.func1()
        go.ngrok.com/lib/nsync/group.go:69 +0x44
created by go.ngrok.com/lib/nsync.(*Group).Go
        go.ngrok.com/lib/nsync/group.go:68 +0x128
```

i did not make any changes to the ngrok config

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I spoke with ngrok support and they verified that looks like my isp was blocking something.

They advised to edit the ngroc.yml file and to add

crl_noverify: true

To the the file.

After that the command "ngrok http 80" works as normal.